# ASP.Net WebApi Authentication and Security

Tags: authentication, identity, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity, sts-securitytokenservice

I have been looking at the [Thinktecture.IdentityModel.40](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.40) library as a way of handling the security of my Asp.Net WebApi. One point I don't understand is the following, and this is my question.

When the user authenticates the first time, they need to supply their username and password. If they are authenticated, they are issued a token to use for all the other calls.

Using the above library, I use the method, `AddBasicAuthentication` to the security config.
 Will this by default use the token issuing mechanism, or do I need to use the `AddSimpleWebToken`?

And If so, how do I tie the two mechanisms together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no token issuance yet. I am working on that feature.